# Skype в SuSe Linux

Tags: linux, skype, suse

Как установить skype на SuSe Linux?

Answer (score 1):

подробная инструкция [есть на сайте дистрибутива по-русски](https://ru.opensuse.org/SDB:Skype).

копирую вкратце:

1. надо определить «битность» glibc (32 или 64):

   ```
   $ getconf LONG_BIT
   ```
2. для 32-битной версии дистрибутива *opensuse 12.1+*, зависимости необходимые skype пакету будут установлены автоматически, но в *opensuse 11.4* вам потребуется установить `libstdc++46-32bit`:

   ```
   $ sudo zypper install libstdc++46-32bit
   ```
3. для 64-битной версии дистрибутива *opensuse 12.1+*, чтобы получить звук, вам необходимо будет установить дополнительные 32-битные библиотеки звука, т.к. на большинстве систем *opensuse* используется *pulseaudio*:

   ```
   $ sudo zypper install libpulse0-32bit alsa-plugins-pulse-32bit libphonon4-32bit
   ```
4. скачайте пакет с сайта skype и установите его:

   ```
   $ cd /tmp; wget -O skype.rpm http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-suse
   $ sudo zypper install skype.rpm
   ```